# Cannot access object method in Javascript

Tags: javascript, methods

I declare class user, and then added an object of the class

```
function user(uid, pwd){
    this.uid = uid
    this.pwd = pwd
    function displayAll(){
        document.write(uid)
        document.write(pwd)
    }
}

var Aaron = new user("Aaron", "123")

document.write(Aaron.uid)
```

I want to roll through the properties printing them out one by one, I tried this

```
Aaron.displayAll()
```

which evaluates to nothing, am I missing something?
Any help would be amazing :)

Comment: You need to return this at the end of the function

Comment: The function is declared withing the `user` function, but never binded to it, hence it's not exposed and can't be accessed, resulting in a function available only **inside** the `user` function.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is what prototype chain is for.

```js
function User(uid, pwd) {
  this.uid = uid
  this.pwd = pwd
}

User.prototype.displayAll = function() {
  document.write(this.uid)
  document.write(this.pwd)
}


var aaron = new User("Aaron", "123");


aaron.displayAll();
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way is to use [Class](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes) syntax.

```
class User {
  constructor(uid, pwd) {
    this.uid = uid;
    this.pwd = pwd;
  }

displayAll(){
    document.write(this.uid);
    document.write(this.pwd);
  }
}

var Aaron = new User("Aaron", "123");
Aaron.displayAll();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can change from `function displayAll()` to `this.displayAll = function displayAll()`

```js
function user(uid, pwd)
    {
        this.uid = uid
        this.pwd = pwd
        this.displayAll = function displayAll()
        {
            document.write(uid)
            document.write(pwd)
        }
    }

    var Aaron = new user("Aaron", "123")

    document.write(Aaron.uid)
    Aaron.displayAll();
```